# rndc -k ddns.key status

Tags: bind

```
rndc: unsupported algorithm: HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT
```

I've created a new key using this command:

```
dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 128 -r /dev/urandom -n USER DDNS_UPDATE
```

I didn't found any way to solve this issue, any idea? (avoid change algorithm)

cat /etc/bind/ddns.key

```
key DDNS_UPDATE {
        algorithm HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT;
        secret "my_key";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only algorithm supported by rndc is "hmac-md5".